# I want to stop music by clicking another music button and also started new music from it

Tags: java, android

I want to stop music by clicking another music button and also started new music from it. How can I do this?

This is my MediaPlayer code:

```
MediaPlayer testSong, testSong2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    testSong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.music1);
    testSong2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.music2);
}

**//Want to stop this music Button, and music.**
public void PlayIt(View view) {
    if (!testSong.isPlaying()){
        testSong.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, "music1 playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        testSong.pause();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

**//When this Button is clocked, and also start this music**

public void PlayIt2(View view) {
    if (!testSong2.isPlaying()){
        testSong2.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, "music2 playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        testSong2.pause();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you want but you can call testSong2.performClick() if it help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I  understood what you want correct. You need to create a manager class that will handle everything for you. Something like this:

```
  import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.Objects;
        import java.util.UUID;
        
        public class MediaPlayerManager {
            
            public final HashMap<String, MediaPlayer> mediaPlayerList;
            public final ArrayList<String> keys;
            private String pausedPlayerKey;
            
            public MediaPlayerManager(MediaPlayer... mediaPlayers) {
                mediaPlayerList = new HashMap<>();
                keys = new ArrayList<>();
                if (mediaPlayers != null && mediaPlayers.length > 0) {
                    for (MediaPlayer mediaPlayer : mediaPlayers) {
                        String uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                        keys.add(uid);
                        mediaPlayerList.put(uid, mediaPlayer);
                    }
                }
            }
    
     public boolean isAnyOnePlaying(){
            for (String key : keys) {
                MediaPlayer player = mediaPlayerList.get(key);
                if (player != null && player.isPlaying()) {
                   return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        
            public void pauseIfPlaying() {
                for (String key : keys) {
                    MediaPlayer player = mediaPlayerList.get(key);
                    if (player != null && player.isPlaying()) {
                        player.pause();
                        pausedPlayerKey = key;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

public void stopIfPlaying() {
            for (String key : keys) {
                MediaPlayer player = mediaPlayerList.get(key);
                if (player != null && player.isPlaying()) {
                    player.stop();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
            public void resume() {
                if (pausedPlayerKey != null) {
                    if (mediaPlayerList.containsKey(pausedPlayerKey) && mediaPlayerList.get(pausedPlayerKey) != null) {
                        Objects.requireNonNull(mediaPlayerList.get(pausedPlayerKey)).start();
                        pausedPlayerKey = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        
    }
```

then in onCreate method you have to create your manager and pass all songs to it.

```
MediaPlayerManager mpm = new MediaPlayerManager({testSong, testSong2});
```

Then define your buttons like this:

```
PlayIt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mpm.isAnyOnePlaying()){
                mpm.stopIfPlaying();
                testSong.start();
            }
        });
```

and same code for PlayIt2 button.
This MediaPlayerManager also allow you to implement Play/Pause button with pauseIfPlaying() and resume() methods